# How can I extract the data from an open or closed spreadsheet and leave the spreadsheet available for other users?

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010

I have calculated some values in a number of spreadsheets and want to pull these values into one spreadsheet and create a graph. I simply copied the cells  from the various spreadsheet and pasted the links into my main spreadsheet. When I open my main spreadsheet it appears to also open all the various spreadsheets I am pulling data from.

I need to extract the data from an open or closed spreadsheet and leave the spreadsheet available for other users. Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Welcome to Super User. What have you researched or attempted so far to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

Technically Excel is not a mult-user product.  In some cases Excel will allow multiple users to open the files, but only in **read-only** mode.  Only 1 user can write to the files at once.

If you use Google Spreadsheet it is a mult-user spreadsheet.

If you store all your data in a database and link to it via excel, multiple people can link to database at once.